# UIView.transition shows parent view with dark background (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, flip

While flipping, the parent view fades into black (from white) to the middle of the animation, then fades into white again... Why?

My code:

```
    if !cardFrontView.isHidden {
        let transitionOptions: UIViewAnimationOptions = [.transitionFlipFromRight, .showHideTransitionViews]
        UIView.transition(from: cardFrontView, to: cardBackView, duration: 1.0, options: transitionOptions, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        let transitionOptions: UIViewAnimationOptions = [.transitionFlipFromLeft, .showHideTransitionViews]
        UIView.transition(from: cardBackView, to: cardFrontView, duration: 1.0, options: transitionOptions, completion: nil)
    }
```

I also tried **UIView.transition(with:** but I have another problem there: round corners are disappearing.

Struggling all day with this... I mean that's all the code.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]

Comment: Try setting BaseView Color to clear if it helps you

Comment: The base view color was white... setting it to transparent did the job! Thanks. Post the answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: I did Posted , Happy to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting BaseView Color to `UIColor.clear` instaed of `UIColor.white`

Comment: What is the BaseView color you are referring to? I have the same issue, but can't figure out how to sort it.

Comment: @Niklas probably he means the superview/parent view.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference though